# Adjust all rows in entire workbook

Tags: excel

I have been sent a workbook with over 100 sheets. For some reason that I can't fathom, all of the rows in each sheet that I have checked have been set so that the height of the rows is 4.5, and therefore it is impossible to see that much the content. The font size has also been set to 2 for all cells in all sheets.

Is there a way (without using VBA if possible) to adjust the cell heights of all the rows, and fonts of all the cells, in each sheet in the workbook at once?

It is easy to do in a single sheet but I don't want to have to repeat it 100+ times. If necessary VBA solution would also be greatly appreciated but I'd prefer another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this little bit of VBA would help.

```
Sub reformat()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws in Sheets
    ws.Cells.Font.Name="Arial"
    ws.Cells.Font.Size=10
    ws.Columns.AutoFit
    ws.Rows.AutoFit
  Next
End Sub
```